# useEffect with debounce

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create an input field that has its value de-bounced (to avoid unnecessary server trips). 
The first time I render my component I fetch its value from the server (there is a loading state and all).

Here is what I have (I omitted the irrelevant code, for the purpose of the example).

This is my debounce hook:

```
export function useDebounce(value, delay) {
  const [debouncedValue, setDebouncedValue] = useState(value);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = setTimeout(() => {
      setDebouncedValue(value);
    }, delay);

    return () => clearTimeout(handler);
  }, [value, delay]);

  return debouncedValue;
}
```

(I got this from: https://usehooks.com/useDebounce/)

Right, here is my component and how I use the `useDebounce` hook:

```
function ExampleTitleInput(props) {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState(props.title || "");
  const [lastCommittedTitle, setLastCommittedTitle] = useState(title);
  const [commitsCount, setCommitsCount] = useState(0);

  const debouncedTitle = useDebounce(title, 1000);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTitle(props.title || "");
  }, [props.title]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (debouncedTitle !== lastCommittedTitle) {
      setLastCommittedTitle(debouncedTitle);
      setCommitsCount(commitsCount + 1);
    }
  }, [debouncedTitle, lastCommittedTitle, commitsCount]);

  return (
    <div className="example-input-container">
      <input
        type="text"
        value={title}
        onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)}
      />
      <div>Last Committed Value: {lastCommittedTitle}</div>
      <div>Commits: {commitsCount}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the parent component:

```
function App() {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setTitle("This came async from the server"), 2000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Example</h1>
      <ExampleTitleInput title={title} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I run this code, I would like it to ignore the debounce value change the first time around (only), so it should show that the number of commits are 0, because the value is passed from the props. Any other change should be tracked. Sorry I've had a long day and I'm a bit confused at this point (I've been staring at this "problem" for far too long I think).

I've created a sample:

https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-dust-mih5d

It should show the number of commits being 0 and the value set correctly without the debounce to change.

I hope I'm making sense, please let me know if I can provide more info.

**Edit**

This works exactly as I expect it, however it's giving me "warnings" (notice dependencies are missing from the deps array):

```
function ExampleTitleInput(props) {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState(props.title || "");
  const [lastCommittedTitle, setLastCommittedTitle] = useState(title);
  const [commitsCount, setCommitsCount] = useState(0);

  const debouncedTitle = useDebounce(title, 1000);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTitle(props.title || "");
    // I added this line here
    setLastCommittedTitle(props.title || "");
  }, [props]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (debouncedTitle !== lastCommittedTitle) {
      setLastCommittedTitle(debouncedTitle);
      setCommitsCount(commitsCount + 1);
    }
  }, [debouncedTitle]); // removed the rest of the dependencies here, but now eslint is complaining and giving me a warning that I use dependencies that are not listed in the deps array

  return (
    <div className="example-input-container">
      <input
        type="text"
        value={title}
        onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)}
      />
      <div>Last Committed Value: {lastCommittedTitle}</div>
      <div>Commits: {commitsCount}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here it is: https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-perlman-w8uug

This works, fine, but I'm worried about the warning, it feels like I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 5):

A simple way to check if we are in the first render is to set a variable that changes at the end of the cycle. You could achieve this using a ref inside your component:

```
const myComponent = () => {
    const is_first_render = useRef(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        is_first_render.current = false;
    }, []);

    // ...
```

You can extract it into a hook and simply import it in your component:

```
const useIsFirstRender = () => {
    const is_first_render = useRef(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        is_first_render.current = false;
    }, []);

    return is_first_render.current;
};
```

Then in your component:

```
function ExampleTitleInput(props) {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState(props.title || "");
    const [lastCommittedTitle, setLastCommittedTitle] = useState(title);
    const [updatesCount, setUpdatesCount] = useState(0);
    const is_first_render = useIsFirstRender(); // Here

    const debouncedTitle = useDebounce(title, 1000);

    useEffect(() => {
        setTitle(props.title || "");
    }, [props.title]);

    useEffect(() => {
        // I don't want this to trigger when the value is passed by the props (i.e. - when initialized)
        if (is_first_render) { // Here
            return;
        }

        if (debouncedTitle !== lastCommittedTitle) {
            setLastCommittedTitle(debouncedTitle);
            setUpdatesCount(updatesCount + 1);
        }
    }, [debouncedTitle, lastCommittedTitle, updatesCount]);

    // ...
```

Comment: I think this is a fine example of how useEffect actually works and how to use debounce with the useEffect function. The way comments are placed is just enough to figure out what is going on. It maybe would be useful to add the necessary import statement to complete the whole code.

Comment: This still executes multiple times, with `is_first_render` being false for about 3 runs before it shows as true. Which sounds like a race condition

Comment: @DouglasGaskell Could you point me to a working example where this is happening?

Answer (score 3):

You can change the `useDebounce` hook to be aware of the fact that the first set debounce value should be set immediately. `useRef` is perfect for that:

```
export function useDebounce(value, delay) {
  const [debouncedValue, setDebouncedValue] = useState(value);
  const firstDebounce = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (value && firstDebounce.current) {
      setDebouncedValue(value);
      firstDebounce.current = false;
      return;
    }

    const handler = setTimeout(() => {
      setDebouncedValue(value);
    }, delay);

    return () => clearTimeout(handler);
  }, [value, delay]);

  return debouncedValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I appreciate it. I didn't think of using `useRef` in the debounce hook. It definitely "feels" like the right solution (especially due to the fact that I use it in other components and I have the exact same issue), however I couldn't really get it to work, here it is (maybe I'm missing something): https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-taussig-piwii

Comment: Also, if it's not too much to ask - Any way you could take a look at my edit and tell me if this approach is wrong? Thanks again, really.

Comment: well, the “commit” count should be 0.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can improve your code in some ways:

First, do not copy `props.title` to a local state in `ExampleTitleInput` with useEffect, as it may cause excessive re-renders (the first for changing props, than for changing state as an side-effect). Use `props.title` directly and move the debounce / state management part to the parent component. You just need to pass an `onChange` callback as a prop (consider using `useCallback`).

To keep track of old state, the correct hook is `useRef` [(API reference)](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref).

If you do not want it to trigger in the first render, you can use a custom hook, such as `useUpdateEffect`, from `react-use`: https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/src/useUpdateEffect.ts, that already implements the `useRef` related logic.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. Can you just clarify, what do you men by using `props.title` "directly"? Do you mean removing the state altogether from the component and pulling it to the parent?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Transform it in to a controlled input (https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)