# Debounce or throttle with react hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, throttling

I need to make an api request when a search query param from an input fields changes, but only if the field is not empty.

I am testing with several answers found on this site, but can't get them working

Firstly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57547582/useeffect-with-debounce) one with a custom hook

```
export function useDebounce(value, delay) {
  const [debouncedValue, setDebouncedValue] = useState(value);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = setTimeout(() => {
      setDebouncedValue(value);
    }, delay);

    return () => clearTimeout(handler);
  }, [value, delay]);

  return debouncedValue;
}
```

now in my component I do this

```
const debouncedTest = useDebounce(() => {console.log("something")}, 1000);
```

but this seems to gets called every rerender regardless of any parameter, and I need to be able to call it inside a useEffect, like this

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (query) {      
    useDebounce(() => {console.log("something")}, 1000);
  } else {
    //...
  }
}, [query]);
```

which of course does not work

Another approach using lodash

```
const throttledTest = useRef(throttle(() => {
  console.log("test");   
}, 1000, {leading: false}))
```

But how would i trigger this from the useEffect above? I don't understand how to make this work

Thank you

Comment: can u explain what you want to get out of this debounce? the api called too quickly or the button is clicked too many time ? what is the issue. Make sure you have a working code with `debounce` first. This way we can help u to add that in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hook's signature is not the same as when you call it.

Perhaps you should do something along these lines:

```js
const [state, setState] = useState(''); // name it whatever makes sense
const debouncedState = useDebounce(state, 1000);

useEffect(() => {
  if (debouncedState) functionCall(debouncedState);
}, [debouncedState])
```

Answer (score 1):

I can quickly point out a thing or two here.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (query) {      
    useDebounce(() => {console.log("something")}, 1000);
  } else {
    //...
  }
}, [query]);
```

technically you can't do the above, `useEffect` can't be nested.

Normally `debounce` isn't having anything to do with a hook. Because it's a plain function. So you should first look for a solid debounce, create one or use `lodash.debounce`. And then structure your code to call `debounce(fn)`. `Fn` is the original function that you want to defer with.

Also `debounce` is going to work with cases that changes often, that's why you want to apply debounce to reduce the frequency. Therefore it'll be relatively uncommon to see it inside a `useEffect`.

```
  const debounced = debounce(fn, ...)
  const App = () => {
    const onClick = () => { debounced() }
    return <button onClick={onClick} />
  }
```

There's another common problem, people might take debounce function inside `App`. That's not correct either, since the `App` is triggered every time it renders.

I can provide a relatively more detailed solution later. It'll help if you can explain what you'd like to do as well.